# ikvm Unhandled Exception: System.TypeLoadException

Tags: java, c#, jxl, ikvm, jni4net

I am new for IKVM. I just created the java project with JXL dependent jar to read and write excel files. and converted this project to DLL files by using IKVMC command.

```
ikvmc { jxl.jar -out:jxl.dll } { Sample.jar -out:sample.dll }
```

Java Code :

[image]

C# Code :

[image]

Exception :

[image]

Exception :

```
Exception thrown: 'System.TypeLoadException' in jxl.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeLoadException' occurred in 
jxl.dllMethod 'thenComparing' in type 'ColumnInfoComparator' from assembly 
'jxl, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have 
an implementation.
```

Can you please help me to solve the issue. how can I add dependent jar's in c-sharp using IKVM?